# Android Phone recognized as "Two Pane" layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, master-detail

I'm writing an application that has two different layout:

- two pane (master-detail) for tablet (screen over 820 dp)
- single pane (master + activity) for phones (screen under 820 dp)

I'm testing my application on different devices and I have different (and unexpected) behaviours:
on **Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10''** (1280x800) I get the two pane layout - *as expected*; but when I try it on my **LG Nexus 5** (1920x1080) or **LG G2 Mini** (960x540) i expect to get the single pane layout, things that don't happen and I still get the two pane layout.

In my project i have a folder named **values-w820p** that contains the file *refs.xml* - as said in [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-using-fragments--mobile-13886) guide.

Also the activity I use check if there is room for a two pane layut on method **onCreate** - here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_list_container);

    //some creation code

    if (findViewById(R.id.settings_detail_container) != null) {
        Log.i("Two panes", "two panes");

        mTwoPane = true;

        //some two pane handling

    }
}
```

Where I go wrong?
Why i can't have a single pane layout on "small" screen?

**EDIT: SOLVED**
The solution is to put the "two pane" layout under *layout-large* and the "single" layouts under *layout*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing size with density. You can certainly have a high density small screen: that's exactly what your Nexus 5 is. If you choose a layout via density, you'll get your two-pane layout on a Nexus 5 because it's high density.

You need to be determining the layout on screen size instead.

See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) for details, but you want `values-large` etc. for your folder structure.

Comment: I've tried to delete _values-w820dp_ and replacing it with _values-large_, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Do follow that link and check the details, though. It might be that a Nexus 5 is still "large". You might want to try "xlarge", for instance.

Comment: You should also try adding different `TextView` components to the layouts in the two different folders, just to check for certain which layout you're ending up with.